# What is the difference between a daimon and a mon or kamon?

Tags: symbols

Normally, when I have seen a family crest they are termed mon or kamon. However, I have also seen the term *daimon*. What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[代紋｛だいもん｝](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BB%A3%E7%B4%8B-558545) refers exclusively to the crest of a yakuza group.
Think of it as a 家紋{かもん} for yakuzas.

Answer (score -1):

According to the dictionary "daimon" refers to noble families.
"Mon" and "kamon" are synonymous and refers to families.

だいもん【大門】 社会的に地位の高い家柄。大家 (たいけ) 。
もん【門】家柄。一族。
かもん【家門】 家柄 (いえがら) 。家筋。
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/134625/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%84%E3%82%82%E3%82%93/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/220653/meaning/m1u/%E9%96%80/
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/45343/meaning/m0u/

Comment: That differs from what Jimmy says. Currently, I am inclined to believe Jimmy because the daimon I saw was, in fact, a Yakuza daimon.

Comment: "だいもん【大門】" "もん【門】" "かもん【家門】"  <- No no... OP's talking about **代紋** (だいもん), **紋** (もん), 家**紋** (かもん). Not 門(family), but 紋(crest).  　 漢字違うし、意味違う～